# No cursor with Nvidia drivers when gdm or gnome-shell loaded

Tags: drivers, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, gnome-shell

In a fresh Arch install if I install gnome and GDM with the official Nvidia drivers:

```
pacman -S gnome gnome-extra nvidia
systemctl enable gdm.service
nvidia-xconfig
```

I don't have a cursor when `GDM` or `gnome-shell` is loaded. Just after X is initialized, but before GDM loads I can see a cursor, and just after I log in with GDM and before gnome-shell loads I can see the default x cursor.

However, inside of gnome-shell I've got nothing. The mouse works fine, I can move it around, click on things, etc. I just can't actually see where I'm moving it.

I've tried using multiple Nvidia cards, turning off the hardware cursor, and changing the cursor theme in gnome to no avail (at one point I got it to flicker in and out when I pressed the Ctrl key, though I have no idea what change caused that). It also happens with multiple versions of the Nvidia driver, and multiple versions of the Kernel. Right now I'm on 3.6.11, but it also happens on 3.7.

I realize this question is hopelessly vague, and the lack of log files probably make it challenging, but I haven't seen anything out of the ordinary in any of the normal places. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: @luchosrock Thanks; that does make more sense. Should I re-ask, or is it better for a moderator to move it?

Comment: maybe this could help http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-to-migrate-a-question